# Xamarin C# Resource.id does not contain a definition for 'Toolbar'

Tags: c#, xamarin

CS0117 Resource.id does not contain a definition for 'Toolbar'

```
 Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

I honestly Don't understand how to fix this I'm relatively new to C# and especially Xamarin

Comment: Toolbox or toolbar? I am confused ;)

Comment: sorry mistyped that I'm still tired

Comment: Me too, no worries :D

Comment: @ topic: I do not know Xamarin, i just googled 'something'. [Is this helping?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/125522/toolbar-findviewbyid-resource-id-toolbar-toolbar-is-always-null). If you dont trust links, please search for 'xamarin Resource.Id.toolbar'. Good luck!

Comment: `protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            AppCenter.Start("205d4461-a6fc-4dd2-aa56-c41d59448548", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            
       
        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Comment: whoops that didn't work

Comment: Can you provide some more info? Which IDE are you using, VS or VS for Mac?What type of project did you create and what shared code options did you select when creating the Xamarin Forms solution? I have seen this issue on brand new solutions sometimes and IIRC closing the solution and re-opening it resolves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Not really answer, but can be something easy like clean/rebuild solution (not generated id in resource file). Or id not looks like "@+id/textView2". maybe just save file.

Comment: If you feel what you provided is "not really an answer" then please post it as a comment rather than an answer. However a clean and rebuild is something worthwhile to try when resources are showing as undefined when you know they are defined.

Comment: @jgoldberger I know, but cannot add comment and looking at question and "relatively new to C# and especially Xamarin" info could be useful right now. looks like rules here more important then information/help

Comment: @AndrewF Yes, it can be a little problematic to get the first x points here. The good thing about this is, that spamming this site is hard too. Which is even more important, so the board stays clean.